# ionic native page transition scroll too much list

Tags: ionic-framework

I've added native page transition plugin to my existing ionic project and flow by [this article by gajotres](http://www.gajotres.net/handling-native-view-animations-with-ionic-framework/) and after that, all of the lists that have scroll in my project, scroll smooth but too much scroll after content!
Whats the problem?!
(this problem only appear in my android device, not in web view or emulator)

[image]